# Is there a way to flag a bad edit that has already been accepted?

Tags: discussion, flags, edits

Came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30197844/revisions) in the Triage review queue, and noticed both that it had really bad grammar *and* had been edited. Curious, I checked out the edit and it was of the most superficial sort: arguably made the question worse through the addition of inappropriate punctuation.

Is there a way (or, if not, should there be a way) to flag an *edit* that is clearly not up to community standards, but was auto-accepted for some reason?

From the [help section on editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just
>   change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

and:

> Editing a post also bumps the question to the top of the homepage.
>   Please be mindful of this and make your edits count, so that the new
>   attention is brought to something substantial.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a suggested edit; it was an edit by a user with full edit privileges, so the edit being small in scope isn't really much of a problem.  None of the changes look harmful to me, they all seem correct, so just move on.

Comment: I didn't say that it was a suggested edit: even said that it was auto-accepted. That they have full edit privileges doesn't seem relevant - this sort of edit would have been rejected had it gone through the suggested edit queue. That a user is trusted to do an edit is a different thing than saying an edit is correct, or not having tools to flag bad edits.

Comment: The fact that they have edit privs *is* relevant.  As they're not consuming reviewer time, and aren't locking the post, makes the problems with minor edits much lower.  I *highly* doubt this would be rejected even if it were suggested, and it certainly isn't actively harming the post.  If you were to flag this as a problem your flag would most certainly be rejected.